# JQuery event triggered but handler not called

Tags: javascript, jquery, pug, typeahead.js

I'm using the typeahead-addresspicker jquery plugin to provide a autocomplete field and a map for the user to select a location.

The plugin works fine and can find any address or location and put a marker on the map. However, when the address is set I would like to insert the Google Geocode values into form fields. For that I listen to the addresspicker:selected event which is triggered in the code but the handler is not executed.

```
script(src='/js/lib/jquery/jquery-2.1.0.min.js')
script(src='/js/lib/typeahead/typeahead.js')
script(src='/js/lib/typeahead/typeahead-addresspicker.js')
script.
    $.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var addressPicker = new AddressPicker({map: {id: '#map', options:{center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.0360272, 3.7359072), zoom: 8}},
            marker: {draggable: true, visible: true, position:new google.maps.LatLng(51.0360272, 3.7359072)},
            zoomForLocation: 18,
            reverseGeocoding: true});
        $('#address').typeahead(null, {
          displayKey: 'description',
          source: addressPicker.ttAdapter()
        });
        addressPicker.bindDefaultTypeaheadEvent($('#address'));
        $(addressPicker).on('addresspicker:selected', function (event, result) {
            $('#lat_input').val(result.lat());
            $('#lng_input').val(result.lng());
            $('#number_input').val(result.nameForType('street_number'));
            $('#name_input').val(result.nameForType('premise'));
            $('#street_input').val(result.nameForType('street_address'));
            $('#suburb_input').val(result.nameForType('locality'));
            $('#state_input').val(result.nameForType('administrative_area_level_1'));
            $('#postcode_input').val(result.nameForType('postal_code'));
            $('#country_input').val(result.nameForType('country'));
        });
    });
```

Am I missing something about Jquery events?

Comment: If you console log result.lat(), or even the result object, is it properly returned and displayed within your debug console?

Comment: Where should I console log result.lat? The result handler isn't triggered.

Comment: how are you verifying that the result handler is not triggered?

Comment: By putting a breakpoint inside it in Chrome developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, it was the noConflict() function. Removed that and it works fine.